# PHP Mail() Function Issue - Message field not getting sent (WordPress)

Tags: html, function, email, php

I know there are thousands and thousands of ways to utilize the PHP mail() function, but I am fairly new to PHP and could use some pointers to get me set in the right direction. I have a PHP mail function written into my WordPress driven site and it emails all the information (name, email, & phone) except for the message field. I've done my research on here as well as every PHP related site, but I would prefer to understand my specific issue so I can better understand what I'm writing. So with that said...here's the code:

```
<?php

function spamcheck($field)
  {
  $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

  if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
  else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
  }

if (isset($_POST['email']))
  {

  $mailcheck = spamcheck($_POST['email']);
  if ($mailcheck==FALSE)
    {
        $submit_message = "Please input your information again.";
    }
  else
    {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

    mail("emailaddress@gmail.com", "From: $name", "Email: $email", "Phone Number: $phone", "Message: $message");

    $submit_message = "Thank you for your message";
    }
  }
?>
```

And the HTML...

```
<form name="message-me" id="contact-form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="field-group">
                    <label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" id="form_name" />
                </div>
                <div class="field-group">
                    <label>Email:</label><input type="text" name="email" id="form_email" />
                </div>
                <div class="field-group">
                    <label>Phone:</label><input type="text" name="phone" id="form_phone" />
                </div>
                <div class="field-group">
                    <label>Message:</label><textarea rows="4" cols="31" name="message" id="form_message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="field-group">
                    <input type="image" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/Send-Message-Arrow.png" width="90" height="72" class="form-button" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

Any information would be greatly appreciated. As I mentioned, I'm still learning PHP and I really want to understand what I'm writing - not just blindly copying & pasting code all the time. Thanks!

Comment: Then what is your question? message are not sent? any error?..or you just like some document about php mailing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have look at [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

You need to provide parameters as

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Here you have provided "to" email address right.

So this might help you:

```
$message = $_POST['message'];

//Give mail a subject
$subject = "YOUR SUBJECT HERE";

//Header Information for mail
$headers = "YOUR HEADERS INFORMATION HERE";

mail("emailaddress@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $headers);

$submit_message = "Thank you for your message";
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for the information about the headers as well as the PHP documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Your SMTP want to be configured, first check up that
and

```
//Header Information for mail
$headers = "YOUR HEADERS INFORMATION HERE";
$msg="Email: $email<br/>Phone Number: $phone<br/>Message: $message";
mail("emailaddress@example.com", $subject, $msg, $headers);
```

Comment: I replaced the <br/> with \n and that gave the desired message. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Kindly read this manual with the directives and examples on it and you'll understand well what you are doing. Just take your time to read and understand well then start asking your questions from that point. Right now, you don't seem to understand even how the PHP mail() works. Read then get back so together you'll understand any solutions pointed out to you and you won't just copy and paste the solution without being able to solve it tomorrow.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php